# To make Dictionary completely out of user Inputs

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

Is it possible to make a dictionary completely out of user Inputs?
Example:

```
for x in range(1):
    name = input('Dict name :') # user enters: 'Car'
    k = input('Key: ')  # user enters: 'Toyota'
    v = input('Value')  # user enters: 'White'

# To have result: 
car= {'Toyota': 'White'}
```

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. However, naming identifiers based on user input is pointless in most cases. You could do something like `globals()[name] = {k: v}` but you could just as well assign `name ` to a `dict` of `cars` and you wouldn't need to modify the `dict` of `globals()` which would cause nightmares for debugging.

Comment: But that's the point @Axe319 how to assign the variable  name with 'car' as value to a dict. Simply name={k:v} makes a dictionary 'name' not a 'car'.

Answer (score 1):

from what i understand you want something like this right?

```
    array = []
    dict = {}
    for x in range(2):
        obj = {}
        dict_name = input('Name :')
        key = input('Key :')
        obj[key] = input('Value :')
        dict[dict_name] = obj
        print(dict)
    array.append(dict)
    
    # To have result: 
    # car= {'Toyota': 'White'}
    print(array)
```

basically what this does is we create an array first just to append all the objects we will be creating, in the loop we add the obj = {} so we can create a new object every time the loop begins and when the loop finished we append the dicts inside the array

this will result in:

```
 {'car': {'toyota': 'white'}, 'car': {'toyota': 'red'}}
[{'car': {'toyota': 'white'}, 'car': {'toyota': 'red'}}]
```